# How can you make the UI responsive while multiple Fragment Transactions are executing?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my application there is one main activity, which exchanges fragments in it.
There is a loading fragment which loads data to display, and calls a content fragment that displays said data. The content fragment's layout looks like this:

```
<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</ScrollView>
```

When the loading finishes I replace the loading fragment with the content fragment and I add a number of question fragments under its content according to the load results, with this code

```
 FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 for (Qyestion f : myQuestions) 
     trans.add(R.id.content,QuestionFragment.NewInstance(f));
 trans.commit();
```

this works well enough, but when the number of fragments to be added is big (70-80) it takes up to 10 seconds to complete the job.

This is ofcourse understandable, but during that time all I can do is show a frozen progressbar from the loading fragment.

Is there a way to let the progress bar continue animating while the activity is loading?

As a side note , I know that this should optimally be handled with a RecyclerView, but the QuestionFragment class has a lot of functionality behind it and it would be very difficult for me to transfer all of it inside a RecyclerView's adapter.

Comment: Have you tried delegating from the main thread?

Comment: "70-80 fragments" sounds like a mess

Comment: Do they really need to be different fragments or can that be replaced with a more simple, `LayoutInflater` ?

Comment: @Shark could you explain delegating from the main thread please? and yes they have to be fragments, the question fragment has a huge ui logic behind it, what do you mean replace it with a layout inflater? does the layout inflater do other things than just inflate views?

Comment: @AntonMalyshev it is, but originally the application was meant to be as a wizard, so i designed it with an activity that would replace its main fragment with the currently shown question, but after it was created I was asked to change it with a scrolling list of all the questions, and I don't have enough time to rebuild it so it can use a recyclerview to handle the fragments

Comment: "Delegating from the main thread" means running things in `AsyncTask`. That should at least let your progressbar spin while the fragments are loading.

Comment: @Shark yeah but wouldn't that cause my application to crash? Don't fragment transactions have to happen in the UI thread since they update the UI?

Comment: You can always run the `transaction.commit()` on the UI thread by invoking `runOnUiThread(...)` but do make sure you initialize (and load) fragments on a background thread; that should speed it up significantly. I'm guessing the initialization/preparation is what takes the most time, and not commiting the transactions themselves.